# JQUERY.COUNTO.JS: On Scroll Count Numbers NOT OnLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working with one page website and I want to add a counting numbers with it, so I use [javascript.countTo.js](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo). I created every section to group related data and I put the **section counter** **`<section id="counters">`** below my portfolio section **`<section class="justaddheight portfolio">`**. Everytime the page load the number count and when I scroll I always see that numbers stop or ended it's counting. Now, I want the number counts when I scroll and get into the **section counter** **`<section id="counters">`**. In addition, I used [WOW.js](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/) and [easingJS](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) with my site, it's the best if you combined the code with it, but it also  acceptable if not. The code are the following below:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><!--The Viewport-->
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> <!--Character Set-->
        <meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache"> <!--The No-Cache-->

        <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            CSS 
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Font-Awesome -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Icomoon-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
        <!-- Simple Line Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simple-line-icons.css">     
        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


        <!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            JAVASCRIPT 
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Wow -->
        <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Counter -->
        <script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
        <!--Easing-->
        <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>        
        <!--Custom JS-->
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="top">
        <section class="justaddheight text-center about" >
            <h1>SCROLL DOWN</h1>
            <p>First, Scroll Now</p>
            <p>Second, try Again but wait for few seconds before scroll to identify.</p>
        </section>
         <section class="justaddheight service">

        </section>
         <section class="justaddheight portfolio">

        </section>
        <section id="counters">
            <div class="ace-overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
                            <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-briefcase to-animate-2"></i>
                            <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="89" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">89</span>
                            <span class="ace-counter-label">Finished projects</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
                            <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-code to-animate-2"></i>
                            <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="2343409" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">2343409</span>
                            <span class="ace-counter-label">Templates</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
                            <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-cup to-animate-2"></i>
                            <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="1302" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">1302</span>
                            <span class="ace-counter-label">Cup of coffees</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
                            <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-people to-animate-2"></i>
                            <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="52" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">52</span>
                            <span class="ace-counter-label">Happy clients</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

<style type="text/css">
    /* USE JUST TO ADJUST HEIGHT*/
    .justaddheight{
        height: 500px;
    }
    .text-center{
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.counter-number').countTo();
</script>
```

Comment: If you need to detect when it comes into view, there is an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrollinghttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if the element is scrolled into view, I'll use function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22480938/2025923).

Now, we can check if the element `#counters` is in view by using below function

```
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
    var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

    var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
    return isVisible;
}
```

This first gets the bounding points using [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect). This returns `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right`, `width` and `height` of the element on which the method is called. These can be used to detect if element is inside view.
`top` and `bottom` are taken from this object and checked if element bottom is less than window height.

---

First of all, bind `scroll` event on the `window`. Inside the handler, check if element is in the view. When element comes in the view, then call the plugin on elements and unbind the `scroll` event.

```js
function isScrolledIntoView(el) {
  var elemTop = el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  var elemBottom = el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;

  var isVisible = (elemTop >= 0) && (elemBottom <= window.innerHeight);
  return isVisible;
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  if (isScrolledIntoView(document.getElementById('counters'))) {
    $('.ace-counter-number').countTo();

    // Unbind scroll event
    $(window).off('scroll');
  }
});
```

```css
.justaddheight {
  height: 500px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-countto/1.2.0/jquery.countTo.js"></script>

<section class="justaddheight text-center about">
  <h1>SCROLL DOWN</h1>
  <p>First, Scroll Now</p>
  <p>Second, try Again but wait for few seconds before scroll to identify.</p>
</section>
<section class="justaddheight service">

</section>
<section class="justaddheight portfolio">

</section>
<section id="counters">
  <div class="ace-overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-briefcase to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="89" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="100">89</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Finished projects</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-code to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="2343409" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">2343409</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Templates</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-cup to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="1302" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">1302</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Cup of coffees</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ace-counter to-animate">
          <i class="ace-counter-icon icon-people to-animate-2"></i>
          <span class="ace-counter-number js-counter" data-from="0" data-to="52" data-speed="5000" data-refresh-interval="50">52</span>
          <span class="ace-counter-label">Happy clients</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/grv9o0h0/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [appear.js](http://creativelive.github.io/appear/) plugin which provides event triggers for elements when they appear, disappear and reappear in the viewport.

```
<span class='count'>50</span>
```

And the JS

```
appear({
  init: function init() {},
  elements: function elements() {
    // Track all elements with the class "count"
    return document.getElementsByClassName('count');
  },
  appear: function appear(el) {
    $(el).countTo({
      from: 0,
      to: $(el).html(),
      speed: 1300,
      refreshInterval: 60
    });
  },
  disappear: function disappear(el) {},
  bounds: 200,
  reappear: true
});
```